# Construct project operator given its Kernel

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, linear-transformations

Let $P$ be a project operator on $\mathbb{C}^N$, i.e. $P^2=P$, and providing two matrices (or subspace of $\mathbb{C}^N$) , say, $N_1$ and $M_1$, which satisfy that:
$$\text{Im }P =N_1$$
$$\text{Im }(1-P) =M_1$$

Of course, for project operator we have $\text{Im }P =\text{ker} (1-P)$.

My question is how to find (construct ) such $P$ provide $M_1$ and $N_1$?

Answer (score 1):

You already noted that $\text{Im}(P) = \ker(1-P)$, but we also have that $\text{Im}(1-P) = \ker(P)$: indeed, suppose that $v \in \text{Im}(1 - P)$, then there is some $w$ such that $w - Pw = v$ and hence we have that 
$$Pv = Pw - P^2w = 0.$$
Analogously, suppose that $v \in \ker(P)$, then we have that $(1-P)v = v$, so $v \in \text{Im}(1-P)$. Therefore, your conditions translate to 
$$\begin{cases}
\text{Im}(P) &= N_1\\
\ker(P) &= M_1
\end{cases}.$$

Because of the dimension theorem, you know that this will not be possible for all matrices $N_1$, $M_1$, since we need to end up with a dimension $n$ (considering you work with the vectorspace $\mathbb{C}^n, \mathbb{C}, +$).

If your matrices have the right dimensions, then you can pick any set of linearly independent columns or rows of the matrix $N_1$ and use columns of $M_1$ to find a basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$. Using this basis and the fact that $\text{Im}(P) \cap \ker(P)$, the matrix corresponding to this basis will have the following form (in order to get the zeros, you might have to use Gram-Schmidt orthonormality procedure to make the vectors comming from the $M_1$ matrix to be orthogonal to $\text{Im}(P)$):
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 &\ldots & 0\\
0 & 1 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0\\
  &   & \ddots &   & 0 & \ldots & 0\\
0 & 0 & \ldots & 1 & 0 & \ldots & 0\\
0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & &\vdots &\vdots & &\vdots \\
0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0
\end{pmatrix} $$
where the identity block matrix in the upper left corner has dimension equal to the dimension of the image and the kernel has dimension $n - \dim(\text{Im}(P))$ (because of the dimension theorem).

$\textbf{Remark:}$ this is always possible if you would only have that $\text{Im}(P) = N_1$, since you could then take its columnspace and added enough (orthogonal) vectors to find a base. So in general you will need extra conditions on the second matrix (for example that the columnspace of $M_1$ complements the columnspace of $N_1$).

$\textbf{Remark 2:} $ We can not really speak about the image being a matrix, only about the columns spanning the image, so this is how in interpreted your question.